# Get unique products between lists and maintain order of input

Tags: python, unique, generator, cartesian-product

There are quite a lot of questions about the unique (Cartesian) product of lists, but I am looking for something peculiar that I haven't found in any of the other questions.

My input will always consist of two lists. When the lists are identical, I want to get all combinations but when they are different I need the unique product (i.e. order does not matter). *However*, in addition I also need the order to be preserved, in the sense that the order of the **input** lists matters. In fact, what I need is that the items in the first list should always be the first item of the product tuple.

I have the following working code, which does what I want with the exception I haven't managed to find a good, efficient way to keep the items ordered as described above.

```
import itertools

xs = ['w']
ys = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def get_up(x_in, y_in):
    if x_in == y_in:
        return itertools.combinations(x_in, 2)
    else:
        ups = []
        for x in x_in:
            for y in y_in:
              if x == y:
                  continue
              # sort so that cases such as (a,b) (b,a) get filtered by set later on
              ups.append(sorted((x, y)))
        ups = set(tuple(up) for up in ups)
        return ups

print(list(get_up(xs, ys)))
# [('c', 'w'), ('b', 'w'), ('a', 'w')]
```

As you can see, the result is a list of unique tuples that are ordered alphabetically. I used the sorting so I could filter duplicate entries by using a set. But because the first list (`xs`) contains the `w`, I want the tuples to have that `w` as a first item.

```
[('w', 'c'), ('w', 'b'), ('w', 'a')]
```

If there's an overlap between two lists, the order of the items that occur in both lists don't matter., so for `xs = ['w', 'a', 'b']` and `ys = ['a', 'b', 'c']` the order for `a` doesn't matter

```
[('w', 'c'), ('w', 'b'), ('w', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
                                         ^
```

or

```
[('w', 'c'), ('w', 'b'), ('w', 'a'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c')]
                                                     ^
```

Preferably I'd end up with a generator (as `combinations` returns). I'm also only interested in Python >= 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the tuples in an order-preserving way (as when the lists are identical),  then filter by removing tuples whose inverse is also in the list.

```
if x_in == y_in:
        return itertools.combinations(x_in, 2) 
    else:
        seen = set()
        for a,b in itertools.product(x_in, y_in):
            if a == b or (b, a) in seen:
                continue
            else:
                yield (a,b)
                seen.add((a,b))
```

This will give you the tuples in `(x, y)` order; when both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` occur, you get only the order seen first.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an answer to my own question, though I bet there is a better solution using itertools or others.

```
xs = ['c', 'b']
ys = ['a', 'b', 'c']


def get_unique_combinations(x_in, y_in):
    """ get unique combinations that maintain order, i.e. x is before y """
    yielded = set()
    for x in x_in:
        for y in y_in:
            if x == y or (x, y) in yielded or (y, x) in yielded:
                continue

            yield x, y
            yielded.add((x, y))

    return None

print(list(get_unique_combinations(xs, ys)))
```